# Найти все вхождения по регулярке в vim

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vim

Нужно достать список атрибутов, которые используются в огромном html файле. Не могу составить регулярку под атрибут в виме. Пробую примерно такой вариант: (.+\?)=".
Подскажите так же, как потом все выделенное регуляркой скопировать в другой файл?

Comment: если `(.+\?)="` — это ленивое выражение, то vim, вообще говоря, их не поддерживает, но есть свой синтаксис: `.{-}` аналогичный `.*?`. Смотри `:help non-gready`

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

Вы все еше редактируте HTML вручную, тогда мы идем к вам!

```
~$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

или

```
~# apt-get install python-bs4
```

*из документации*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html_doc = """ <html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head> <body> <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p> <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>, <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>; and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p> <p class="story">...</p> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

soup.title
# <title>The Dormouse's story</title> 

soup.title.name 
# u'title' 

soup.title.string
# u'The Dormouse's story' 

soup.title.parent.name
# u'head' 

soup.p
# <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p> 

soup.p['class']
# u'title' 

soup.a

# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>

soup.find_all('a')

# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>, 
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>, 
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.find(id="link3")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/